# Count All Unique and Existing Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

**Membership**

```
ID    MemberID    UserID    UserID2
1     7           1         0
2     6           4         1
3     4           6         12
4     2           8         18
5     1           1         4
6     3           7         0
```

I used this SQL statement:

**SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CHECKSUM(UserID, UserID)) FROM Membership**

but I am getting only 6

I want to get all the unique records both for columns UserID and UserID2.

1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 18 (excluding 0) = 7

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the distinct values, try doing a `union all` first:

```
select count(distinct UserId)
from ((select UserId from MemberShip
      ) union all
      (select UserId2 from Membership
      )
     ) mu
where UserId <> 0;
```

EDIT:

The following version is mentioned in the comments:

```
select count(*)
from ((select UserId from MemberShip
      ) union
      (select UserId2 from Membership
      )
     ) mu
where UserId <> 0;
```

I prefer the `union all` version because I generally avoid `union` as much as possible.  The extra step of removing duplicates always imposes additional performance -- although useful here, it is often not needed.  That is why I prefer the `union all` version.

Although not simpler (in my opinion), this version has one possible small advantage in some databases.  If the `Membership` table has separate indexes on `UserId` and `UserId2`, then it is easier to take advantage of these indexes for the query.  Note that this does *not* eliminate the de-duping (because the lists of users from both columns need to be de-duped), but it does (potentially) reduce the volume of members in the de-duping step.

Comment: Do you need a `union all` and a `distinct`? Surely `select COUNT(*) from (select userid from membership union select userid2 from membership) t where userid<>0` is simpler?

Comment: @podiluska . . . See the edited version.  The short version is that your formulation is totally reasonable, I just avoid using `union`.